# Android Alarm Manager Set Repeating every six month at Specific Date

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I want to repeat my task on every six month. I have the following code also I have another problem with this code, i want start alarm from 9/3/2018 but alarm started from 9/4/2018

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private AlarmManager AlarmManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        AlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);

        AlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Months are zero-based in `Calendar`. `3` is `Calendar.APRIL`.

Comment: @MikeM. Please explain a little more

Comment: `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);` is setting the month to `Calendar.APRIL`. If you want it to be set for this month, use `2`, or `Calendar.MARCH`.

Comment: Why is it so? This means that I must make the moon negative 1 Example : calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3 - 1);

Comment: "Why is it so?" - Because that's just what the Java language designers decided. "This means that I must make the moon negative" - No, you just need to adjust accordingly. `3 - 1` is not negative. I would mention that if you eventually set that alarm based on the current date/time, `Calendar#get(Calendar.MONTH)` will return the correct value to use with `set()`. Furthermore, other components - like `DatePicker` - will also handle months as zero-based, so you won't need to do anything there, either.

Comment: but in DatePicker  i started month from 1, Because I want to show the correct date to the user  also, i saved the date as I said in the database Example : 16/1/2018

Comment: There is no `DatePicker` in your question. I was merely using that as an example. Furthermore, I'm not sure what you mean by "i started month from 1", but `DatePicker` uses zero-based months; e.g., https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init(int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate(int,%20int,%20int).

Comment: This code is part of the source, Anyway I started the moon from 1 and i saved in my database and I'll take the date from database I think I should make the moon negative 1 in alarmanager- Thank you for your answers